# ember attributes not available in view, only ID

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-cli, json-api

Needless to say, new to Ember and just trying to get a proof of concept done. Already had some help with EmberCLI but this a new oddness for me.

/routes/index.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
   return this.store.findAll('skill');
}});
```

/models/skill.js

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';

export default Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  desc: DS.attr('string'),
  type: DS.attr('string')
});
```

/adapters/application.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'v1',
  host: 'http://edu-api.app:8000',
});
```

/serializers/application.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({});
```

/templates/index.hbs

```
    <h2>Skills</h2>
    <ul>
      {{#each model as |item|}}
    <li>
    <div>
      <li>{{item}} {{item.id}} {{item.type}} {{item.name}} {{item.desc}}</li>
    </div>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

[image]

It seems that the id attr is available and correct, but yet all the other attrs are not being loaded from the json.  If I copy/paste the json and manually set it in the model, it works as expected, so is there some filtering going on when coming from the model store or serializer?

Comment: what does your payload look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSONAPISerializer` and `JSONAPIAdapter` are *not* to for simple JSON/REST Backends but for a fully [`JSONAPI`](http://jsonapi.org) compatible Backend.

You say it works when you copy & paste and set it on the model, so probably you mean something like this:

```
this.store.createRecord('skill', {
    id: '1',
    name: 'foo',
    desc: 'bar',
    type: 'baz'
});
```

This will indeed work for a model creation but is *not* a `JSONAPI` compatible response! In `JSONAPI` you would have something like this (if the request should return multiple entities:

```
{
    data: [{
        id: '1',
        attributes: {
            name: 'foo',
            desc: 'bar',
            type: 'baz'
        }
    }]
}
```

So now you have two options:

1. Make your API `JSONAPI` compatible, or
2. use a different adapter & serializer.

The `RESTSerializer`/`RESTAdapter` are a simple default implementation that can handle a structure like this:

```
{
    id: '1',
    name: 'foo',
    desc: 'bar',
    type: 'baz'
}
```

Also they are highly customizable.

Checkout the [official API](http://emberjs.com/api/data/) for documentation.

Comment: brilliant . thanks @Lux , you did it again. Now I should be on my way!

quick second question, any future proofing of using JSONAPI format?  Im we are building the API so we can do as what we need to the syntax, and it was told that JSONAPI woudl be the best approach, but im rethinking that.